# i am having a problem with start making gui for my classes with inheritance

Tags: class, user-interface, inheritance

as it is my first time making a GUI in java and my project has three class with inheritance and i am confused how to start and having a really hard time.

Comment: You start with deciding on the specifications of your app: what is the goal of the project, what is the purpose of the app, what do you want your GUI to look like to achieve that purpose, how you want your user to use the app,.. etc. You need to ask a _specific_ problem here, and there is very little info on this post (there isn't even code) to allow anyone to help.

Comment: Dear sir how can i upload the code ? Please let me know i am still confused

Comment: Please read the [ask] page and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: okay sir i will day as you  say right away

Comment: and sir how can i ask you questions related to other topics it would be a great help to me